# NSDate format not showing what expected

Tags: ios, nsdate, xcode4.5, nsdateformatter

I have problems printing a date as NSString. I have stored current date and time at certain points of my app lifecycle this way:

```
NSDate *current = [NSDate date];
long currentTime = [current timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Now, I need to show those dates in UILabels. I tried this way:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:currentTime];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

but I'm not getting the correct date nor the time. What could I be missing?

Thanks!

Comment: What's incorrect about it? Why don't you use the `current` variable and format that? Why use the time interval stuff? If you log `date`, is it correct?

Comment: Minor point: time intervals are `double`s, not `long`s, so you're losing some precision there (though it shouldn't have any effect in this context).

Comment: This worked perfectly fine when I tried it (I assume that `[currentDate timeIntervalSince1970]` should be `[current timeIntervalSince1970]`, because `currentDate` is not defined).

Comment: Can you show what you are getting and show what you expect to get so we can see the exact problem?

Comment: Also, date formatters require a timezone to properly format dates (which are stored as seconds since the epoch in UTC), and the timezone is set to the local timezone of the device by default. If your results are off by an amount equal to your UTC offset, consider setting the timezone property of your formatter to the UTC timezone, `[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]`.

Comment: I'm storing the long variable in database and retrieving it later, that's why I need to get the formatted date from the long value. But after formatting I get a date with year 1973 and wrong day and month as well.

Comment: @AppsDev, How about storing as a string in database? Is that possible? You can avoid all these conversion issues then.

Comment: I have checked, it is displaying current time, what do u want?

Comment: @AppsDev whats the problem in it , I have check this code it is displaying "string is= 07/12/2012 - 10:34:10" as I printed in log

Comment: I got it, by setting timezone for the formatter. Now date is correctly displayed, thanks u all for replying!

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

NSString *stringFromDate=[NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:date dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

also you can change the datestyle and timestyle.

Answer (score 0):

Your `currentTime` variable is a `long`, and not an `NSTimeInterval` (a `double`). You are losing not only the fractional part (less important), but the upper range of the time interval. Change it to:

```
NSTimeInterval currentTime = [current timeIntervalSince1970];
```